# Friend was given a guitar with what looks like Chinese handwriting on it (Characters identified: 茶杏銅鑼)

Tags: character-identification, handwriting

Could anyone who's more knowledgeable in language confirm that this is Chinese? My friend knows Japanese, and he says it's definitely not Japanese (unless he's mistaken).

If it is Chinese, could someone translate it to English for me? I've tried many different optical character recognition sites, and none can figure any of the characters out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are written in traditional Chinese: **茶杏銅鑼**, which translated verbatim to **Tea, Apricot, Copper, [Gong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gong).**
The four words together do not resemble anything meaningful. I did a google search with the exact four words but cannot find anything related.

Comment: This is an improvement over Google's automated translation which never suggested the word copper existed in those symbols. It translated as "Apricot Tea Gong" which sounded like a band name to me, but now I'm thinking it might be nicknames for the four members of some band. Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmio92 Nice guess :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

茶杏铜锣 i dont know its meaning. brand name？